# Duplication caused by JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a simple query which contains a JOIN, and this JOIN 'makes' some duplications.

Table users:

```
UserID  Name
------  ----
1       Luis
2       Andre
3       Mark
4       Linda
```

Table bind_groups:

```
groupID UserID
------- ------
26      1
87      2
87      1
12      4
41      4
6       1
21      2
5       3
```

The SQL query:

```
SELECT users.UserID FROM users
    LEFT JOIN bind_groups ON users.UserID = bind_groups.UserID
    WHERE groupID = 26 OR groupID = 87
```

The result will be:

```
UserID
------
1
2
1
```

As you can see, it returns the `UserID = 1` twice (because it appears twice, in groupID 26 and groupID 87).

What should I do if I want to return it one time and not the number of the times it appears in the groups?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use group by clause

```
SELECT users.UserID FROM users
    LEFT JOIN bind_groups ON users.UserID = bind_groups.UserID
    WHERE groupID = 26 OR groupID = 87
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct users.UserID from users ...
```

There is no need for it to be a left join either, your where clause makes it an inner join

Answer (score 2):

Use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.UserID FROM users
    LEFT JOIN bind_groups ON users.UserID = bind_groups.UserID
    WHERE groupID = 26 OR groupID = 87
```

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your sql to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.UserID FROM users
    LEFT JOIN bind_groups ON users.UserID = bind_groups.UserID
    WHERE groupID = 26 OR groupID = 87
```

Answer (score 2):

DISTINCT is clear, but depending on the table sizes it can be useful to work with `IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.UserID FROM users
    JOIN bind_groups ON users.UserID = bind_groups.UserID
    WHERE groupID IN(26, 87)
```